# mercurial repo with multiple customer branches

Tags: mercurial

My question is similar to: [Mercurial branches with different codebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13380314/mercurial-branches-with-different-codebase)

But the solution given there was to do all the work on the one customer branch and merge it to default. I don't see how that is workable in my case.

I have a project that gets distributed to 4 customers. I've setup a named branch for each customer. What is an effective way of merging changes to common code, while leaving alone some customer specific data and/or requirements?

Edit:

I have customers a,b,c. Machines M,N. and parts 1,2,3,4,5.

Right now I have subrepos a,b,c,M,N,1,2,3,4,5 and repos aM1,aM2,bM1,bN1,... . I am considering having subrepo customer (branches a,b,c). machine (branches M,N). parts (1,2,3,4,5)

Are there techniques for making change propagation easy, but also keeping some differences permanent. Maybe something like this:
[TipsAndTricks](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Keep_.22My.22_or_.22Their.22_files_when_doing_a_merge).

Comment: This seems like a faulty design. Why not make more of the functionality configurable or create some very basic plugins? You probably don't want customer-specific functionality---and definitely don't want customer-specific data---in your main project's source tree.

Comment: I understand your point. I guess I'm interested in a more general question. If there are very similar projects, can a few changesets (having to do with customer, build/target, use, test ...) in a branch be marked to not propagate in future merges?

Comment: I appreciate that you made an effort to look for similar questions first.  (+1)

Comment: Are you merging / do you want to merge *from* the customer branches or only *to* them?

Answer (score 3):

Based on your question and clarifying comment, what you want is both impossible and not really what hg is supposed to do.

Everything I am about to say, I say as someone who has made exactly the kind of mistake you are about to make and who has lived to regret it (and slowly, painfully, try to undo it).

As I said in the comments, this seems like a faulty design. If you want something to be part of a code base only for some purposes, then that's a good indicator that what you really need is one of the following:

- **more configurability** to turn features on or off,
- **a custom build script** to assemble various versions of the project, or
- **a core code base and several customer- or purpose-specific code bases for plugins and add-ons**.

You probably don't want customer-specific functionality---and definitely don't want customer-specific data---in your main project's source tree. Anytime you are about to commit a change that includes either customer configurations or code that only one customer will ever use, you need to step back and ask (1) why it should be in your *core* project instead of a plugin and (2) what the implications would be if another customer or third party ever got access to it by mistake.

Comment: His sentence "merge changes to common code" might not necessarily mean "merge from customer branch to common branch", it may just mean "merge the changes I make to our common code into all the customer branches" and that should be completely doable. Not advisable (as you point out) but Mercurial should easily handle that case.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I hadn't thought of it in exactly those terms. If that is indeed what OP means, then I'm not sure what to make of OP's first comment on the question above (about preventing propagation of changes on merges), nor do I understand why the question would be necessary. It's certainly *possible* to maintain a separate branch per customer and only merge to those branches, never from them, as you suggest. But that is pretty self-explanatory and, as you say, still not a good idea.

Comment: I don't think it is likely that he means what I wrote though, much more likely that he means exactly what he writes, he wants to merge partial content from one named branch into the default/common branch. He could obviously do that if he split each customer branch into two parts, the parts of the customer branch that it is safe to merge into common, and the part that is unsafe, but then why couldn't he just write the safe part into the common thread to begin with? Much more likely that he means what he wrote and what you answered to.

Comment: @lasse-v-karlsen  What I tried to do was split into safe/unsafe parts

Comment: @lasse-v-karlsen  The basic design I have is a subRepo for each customer, for each test machine, and for each test unit. Then a repo for each combination that knows how to put the pieces together. But I am wondering if having one repo for all machines with a separate branch for each might make change propagation easier (same for test units, and customers maybe). I am curious whether something like http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Keep_.22My.22_or_.22Their.22_files_when_doing_a_merge could keep the branch specific info in the branch. Or as suggested, merge to branches, graft back

Answer (score 0):

I see at least two possible ways:

- Customer-specific changes are always in separate changesets, and you move common changes from customer-specific branch into mainline **not** with merges, but using `hg graft`, cherry-picking only needed changesets
- Using MQ extension, you can have customer-specific changes in MQ-patches (patch per customer), applied|unapplied individually on demand and just merge branches

In the last case separate named branches *may be not needed at all* (you have `default` and different patch applied for each customer) - at least I moved to this workflow, when I had to maintain a set of clones with only slightly different configurations and merging from default to each branch become boring

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with MQ. Do changes to the patch(s) get tracked?

Comment: @storm - they **can** be versioned (but "changes of changes" are... well... *poorly* readable)

Comment: so if I have default and TargetA branches, and a TargetApatch branch. "hg update TargetA". How to apply TargetApatch - "hg qpush -a"?. How to make changes to TargetApatch? How to make changes that go back to default. pull off the patch "hg qpop -a"?. commit. "update default". "merge TargetA"